# how to set limit searching node in restapifacade for neo4j

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j, cypher, nodes

the below code is working perfectly

```
public void restSearch(String term) {
        IndexManager index = graphDb.index();
        Index<Node> actors = index.forNodes("node_auto_index");
        IndexHits<Node> hits = actors.query("name", term + "*");
        JSONArray json_arr = new JSONArray();
        for (Node node : hits) {
                System.out.println(node.getProperty("name"));
        }

    }
```

but it gives me too much result i want to set limit.
i want only 20 names.

can i optimize this query and set limit here

```
IndexHits<Node> hits = actors.query("name", term + "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cypher:

```
String query = "START n=node: node_auto_index({query}) RETURN n.name";

restApi.query(query,map("query","name:"+term+"*"));
```

Comment: @MichealHunger thanks, but can it be possible using restapi?
without using Cypher.